# issue with urls while moving wordpress from live to local server

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to move a wordpress website to local server.
I am have taken all the steps as mentioned in wordpress support.
Taken backup, database, changed DB name in wp-config.php.
Changed the address in wp-options of DB i 'siteurl' and 'home'.

However, when I open, its redirecting to live server.

I will be glad to hear any help from anyone.

Comment: did you tried giving the localhost url in siteurl and home? Try renaming the plugin folder also then try.

Comment: @Rahul I have changed url of localhost in siteurl and home. What is the exact name of plugin folder in wp-options, can you tell me?

Comment: @Ramis I have taken full backup of the website. Its not live now. I am trying in localhost

Comment: just try renaming the "plugin" folder inside wp-content. and check